# UWP GATT heart rate monitor characteristic value interpretation

Tags: uwp, gatt

I wrote a program that connects to a heart rate modeled but I don't know how to interpret the data.
Here is a sample starting from the first output:

> heart rate is : 16-40-15-04-6D-02-8C-01-0C-04-24-04-AB-03-7B-02-B4-01
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-20-04
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-8F-03
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-10-04

...

> heart rate is : 16-40-F7-03
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-05-04
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-31-04
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-F8-02-47-01
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-A5-03

...

> heart rate is : 16-40-D4-02
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-FE-03
>
> heart rate is : 16-40-15-05
>
> heart rate is : 16-3C-97-03
>
> heart rate is : 16-3D-64-03-78-03
>
> heart rate is : 16-3D-4F-04
>
> heart rate is : 06-3D

...

> heart rate is : 16-3E-3D-04
>
> heart rate is : 16-3E-17-04-78-03

This is the code that gets and converts the data:

```
void hrMeasurementChanged( GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        byte[] hrData = new byte[eventArgs.CharacteristicValue.Length];
        Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(
            eventArgs.CharacteristicValue).ReadBytes(hrData);

        var hrValue = BitConverter.ToString(hrData); 
        Debug.WriteLine("heart rate is : " +hrValue);
    }
```

This page explains it but I am not sure how to interpret the data:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> heart rate is : 16-40-20-04

The first byte is `0x16`, it is `Flags` value field of `heart_rate_measurement`. Its binary form is `0001_0110`, the first bit(the least significant bit) is `Heart Rate Value Format` bit, here it is `0` that means heart rate that following the `Flags` represented by one byte.  Here, heart rate is `0x40`, that is `64` beats per minute(bpm) (decimal form is `64`).  The forth bit is `RR-Interval` bit, here it is `1`, that means one or more `RR-Interval` values are present. `RR-Interval` value is represented by two bytes. Here, there is one `RR-Interval` value, it is `0x0420`(in the order of LSO to MSO).

> heart rate is : 16-40-15-04-6D-02-8C-01-0C-04-24-04-AB-03-7B-02-B4-01

There are eight RR-Interval values from `0x15` to the end.

> heart rate is : 06-3D

The forth bit of `Flags` value field is `RR-Interval` bit, here it is `0`, that means `RR-Interval` values are not present. So there is only heart rate value: `0x3D`.

See also the GATT [heart rate characteristic specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml)